# Are the board positions of the 4 players of each country determined by Elo rating in chess olympiads?

Tags: rules, chess-olympiad

Are the board positions of the 4 players of each country determined by Elo rating in chess olympiads? Or is this something arbitrarily decided by the countries?

By board positions I mean, 1st seed/board, 2nd seed/board, 3rd seed/board and 4th seed/board.
I do remember seeing some players with higher Elo ratings sitting on lower boards, hence I am wondering what the regulations are.

Comment: It would help if everyone can post a comment on why a question is downvoted.

Comment: If I can have a guess, it's specific and answered by a rulebook, and also not many people would actually care (it's more about the games played than by who has to sit where, given most of us won't sit there anyway, like, ever). Personally, I upvote most of what I read, and downvote the rest, but this question just doesn't seem to deserve any of these (imho). Once I know this site better, I might flag for “Read the ******* rulebook”, if there's such a motive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for `fixed board order` in the FIDE handbook's [Regulations for the Chess Olympiad](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=94&view=article). The essence is that the board order cannot be changed between rounds for the purpose of getting a strategic advantage.